# Write $T'(\phi_1)$ and $T'(\phi_2)$. as a linear combination of $\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces, dual-maps

> Define $T : \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2~|~T(x,y,z)=(4x+5y+6z, ~~~7x+8y+9z).$ Suppose $\phi_1,\phi_2$ denote the dual basis of the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2$ and $\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3$ denote the dual basis of the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

(i) Describe the linear functionals $T'(\phi_1)$ and $T'(\phi_2),~ T'$ **represents the dual map of** $T$ .

(ii) Write $T'(\phi_1)$ and $T'(\phi_2)$. as a linear combination of $\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3$

**Attempt: Part(i)** We know that $T'(\phi_1)=\phi_1 \circ T$ and $T'(\phi_2)=\phi_2 \circ T$.

If $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ and $\{e_1,e_2\}$ represent the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R^2$ respectively, Then:

$\omega_1(e_1)=1,~w_1(e_2)=0,~w_1(e_3)=0$

$\omega_2(e_1)=0,~w_2(e_2)=1,~w_2(e_3)=0$

$\omega_3(e_1)=0,~w_3(e_2)=0,~w_3(e_3)=1$

Similarily: $\phi_1(e_1)=1,~\phi_1(e_2)=0$

$\phi_2(e_1)=0, \phi_2(e_2)=1$

Thus, $T'(\phi_1)(x,y,z)= \phi_1 \circ T (x,y,z)= \phi_1 \big (4x+5y+6z, ~~~7x+8y+9z \big )= 4x+5y+6z$

Similarily: $T'(\phi_2)(x,y,z)=7x+8y+9z $

**Part(ii)** $T'(\phi_1)= c_1 \omega_1+c_2 \omega_2+c_3\omega_3$

Thus, $(T' \circ \phi_1~)(x,y,z)= \big( c_1 \omega_1+c_2 \omega_2+c_3\omega_3 \big ) (x+y+z)=c_1x+c_2y+c_3z$

Did I Attempt this correctly? I am not sure about either of the parts!

Any help will be deeply appreciated! Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: I am not familiar with this T' notation, is it just defined to be the composition?

Comment: $T'$  represents the dual map of $T$ .