# Axler: Describe linear functionals $T'\psi_i$ for the linear map $T(x,y,z)=(4x+5y+6z, 7x+8y+9z)$ when $\psi_i$ denote dual basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, duality-theorems

The following is problem 13 from chapter 3F of the third edition of Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*

> Define $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by
>
> $$T(x,y,z)=(4x+5y+6z, 7x+8y+9z)\tag{1}$$
>
> Suppose $\phi_1,\phi_2$ denotes the dual basis of the standard basis
> of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\psi_1, \psi_2, \psi_3$ denotes the dual basis
> of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
>
> (a) Describe the linear functionals $T'(\phi_1)$ and $T'(\phi_2)$.
>
> (b) Write $T'(\phi_1)$ and $T'(\phi_2)$ as linear combinations of
> $\psi_1,\psi_2,\psi_3$.

Someone else has [asked about their solution to this problem before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447034/write-t-phi-1-and-t-phi-2-as-a-linear-combination-of-omega-1-omega), though without any answers.

**Here is my attempt at a solution**

**a)**

By definition of dual basis we have

$$\phi_j v_i=\begin{cases} 1,\ \text{if}\ i=j \\ 0,\ \text{if}\ i\neq j \end{cases},\ i=1,2\tag{2}$$

$$\psi_j w_i=\begin{cases} 1,\ \text{if}\ i=j \\ 0,\ \text{if}\ i\neq j \end{cases},\ i=1,2,3\tag{3}$$

Then, by definition of dual map we have

$$T'\phi_i = \phi_i\circ T \in L(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R})$$

Every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that $T$ maps to $(1,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $T'\phi_1$ maps to 1 and it maps all other vectors to 0.

Similarly, every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that $T$ maps to $(0,1)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $T'\phi_2$ maps to 1 and it maps all other vectors to 0.

Finding such vectors means solving

$$T(x,y,z)=(4x+5y+6z,7x+8y+9z)=(1,0)\tag{4}$$
$$T(x,y,z)=(4x+5y+6z,7x+8y+9z)=(0,1)\tag{5}$$

I'll omit the calculations but the solutions to (4) are $(-4c_1,\frac{7}{3}c_2,0)$ and the solutions to (5) are $(-5c_1,-\frac{4}{3}c_2,0)$.

Thus,

$$T'\phi_1v = \begin{cases} 1,\ \text{if}\ v= (-4c_1,\frac{7}{3}c_2,0) \\
0,\ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\tag{6}$$

$$T'\phi_2v = \begin{cases} 1,\ \text{if}\ v= (-5c_1,-\frac{4}{3}c_2,0) \\
0,\ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\tag{7}$$

**b)**

Since

$$T\psi_1=(4,7)\tag{8}$$
$$T\psi_2=(5,8)\tag{9}$$
$$T\psi_3=(6,9)\tag{10}$$

then the matrix of $T$ relative to the standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 5 & 6\\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{bmatrix}\tag{11}$$

and the matrix of $T'$ relative to the dual bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the transpose of (11) which is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 7 \\
5 & 8 \\
6 & 9
\end{bmatrix}\tag{12}$$

Thus,

$$T'\phi_1 = 4\psi_1 + 5\psi_2+6\psi_3\tag{13}$$

$$T'\phi_2 = 7\psi_1 + 8\psi_2+9\psi_3\tag{13}$$